# MySQL query to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been suggested to migrate from the deprecated MySQL to MySQLi or PDO, I finally got around to it as it'll help my project without wasting too much time. I've been reading a lot on some great articles and websites, but I'd like the best suggestion on how to fetch array with PDO, I can do it with a while loop but I dislike it, how would I convert this current code to PDO.

```
public function User_Details($_iD){
    $_iD = mysql_real_escape_string($_iD);
    $query="SELECT _iD,_iPassword,_iEmail,_iNickname,_iUsername,_iProfilePicture,_iFriendCount FROM users WHERE _iD='$_iD' AND _iStatus='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
return $data;
}
```

I am able with a while loop but as I said, that's not what I'm interested in unless it's a better option.

PDO :

```
$sql = "SELECT _iD,_iPassword,_iEmail,_iNickname,_iUsername,_iProfilePicture,_iFriendCount FROM users WHERE _iStatus='1'";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){
        print $row['_iD'] .' - '. $row['_iUsername'] . '<br />';
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is really not a valid question. You want us to come up with a better solution for you?

Comment: webmaster777 has answered what I asked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would also be wise to actually study how PDO is *different* from old methods instead of trying it the old way with new tools. One of the things that PDO offers is to create prepared [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), which you can execute, and fetch in various ways. I think the [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed to know, I appreciate your answer.